# How to limit the amount of async calls in node js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, throttling

I am trying to limit the amount of async calls I can make to the server to 1 call per second. I looked at async eachOfLimit, but not sure  if this is the right solution.

I'm looking for a library that already exists, that would wrap around the request module and actually throttle requests to 1 per second. I just don't know how to handle this kind of situation, and I'm hoping for some kind of standard.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=throttle

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `express` you can use [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) package from npm. Usage below -

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");


app.enable("trust proxy"); // only if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS ELB, Nginx, etc)

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 1000, // 1 minute
  max: 1 // limit each IP to 1 requests per windowMs
});

//  apply to all requests
app.use(limiter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, how can I add it to the class that contains async functions?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case a little more? This module will allow you to define rate limits on endpoints. You clients will only be able to call the APIs, based on the limit you defined. From the client you just a norma `fetch` call to your server.